# Managing a README.md and vim help for plugins

Tags: help-system, plugin

Is there a way to generate vim help files and a markdown readme for github from the same text file? Or what is the usual strategy for this? I'm maintaining a small plugin that is only used by like four people, but already the vim help is lagging behind the README file. Or is the real solution just diligently writing both?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3752/10604

Comment: definite duplicate, I don't know why I didn't find that question ...