# Making helpfiles from perls POD

Tags: help-system, filetype-perl

Is there a possibility to make vim helpfiles from pers POD?

I know there is `pod2text`, `pod2html`, ...

Is there somting like `pod2vim` too?

---

EDIT:

Example

```perl
=pod

=head1 Headline 1

abc

=head1 Headline 2

cde

=cut
```

should become

```
*lib*    For Vim version ...
...

1. Headline 1 ............ |lib-head1|
2. Headline 2 ............ |lib-head2|

============================================
1. Headline 1           *lib-head1*

abc

============================================
2. Headline 2           *lib-head2*

cde

============================================
 vim:...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? FYI, if you are in a buffer with `filetype=perl` and hit `K`, it will show you Perl's documentation. Seeing both POD and Vim's help have about five grammar rules, it should be possible to write a translator. I'd pick a language that has a reputation for being good at string substitutions using regular expressions ... if only I could think of one ...

Comment: What does your favorite search engine say on the matter?

Comment: @romainl - It says somthing about python/html/... but nothing usable about POD

Comment: @Friedrich - Hi, I have made some perl libraries. There I have used some POD. To give a documentation to my colleagues, I want to make a vim doc.

Comment: That's funny, because I have exactly TWO hits with Google for the query `pod2vim`: one for exactly what you are after and one for some random facebook profile. Try harder.

Comment: Maybe could you have a look at [How do I generate Vim documentation from Markdown notes or inline comments, or are there better ways to add documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3752/23502). If you slightly preprocess your file with [Md2Vim](https://github.com/FooSoft/md2vim?tab=readme-ov-file) you should be close :-)